# TinyMce File not found Error

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using TinyMce Editor 4 in my project. But when i try to load it shows some error say files not found .
e.g.

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
localhost/plugins/tinymce/skins/lightgray/fonts/icomoon.woff

NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
localhost/plugins/tinymce/skins/lightgray/fonts/icomoon.ttf
```

But when I try to search my directory the files are there .

Comment: try to access that file using your browser (with the same path) - what happens?

Comment: i tried this, but the error was same. when i go to my file directory i find the files there.

Comment: i that case the file is not to be found at this location, you will need to check all possibilities. what is the path to your diectory on your hd?

Answer (score 4):

You can just simply solve the problem by adding MIME type to the IIS as follows

1. Open IIS
2. Select your site
3. Select MIME Types
4. Add new From Actions section

> Extention : **.woff**  --> MIME Type : **application/x-woff**

Cheers